# How to create forcibly new http session

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am doing session sharing between two web app(app1 and app2).in app2 once user is validate i want to forcibly create a new session in app2.i am able to do by session.invalidate() and request.getSession(true); but here after doing session.invalidate() app1 session is getting expire.
Pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
request.getSession(true);
```

Comment: yes i dont want to invalidate the old session.Actually i am doing session sharing between two application.if i do this then other application session will invalidate.so pls give me input

Comment: yes i dont want to invalidate the old session.Actually i am doing session sharing between two application.if i do this then other application session will invalidate.so pls give me input

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getSession(false).invalidate();

request.getSession(true).
```

Youcan use this to create